# How does Mathematica resolve symbolic systems of inequalities?

Tags: equation-solving, symbolic, implementation-details, inequalities

Before getting into my question, let me provide some context:

I recently started using *Mathematica* to automatically perform stability analyses that I previously did by hand. A major part of the process requires me to determine (1) which algebraic expressions among a list can possibly become negative, and (2) if any of them are dependent on another (i.e., one expression can only be negative if another is necessarily negative). I have major assumptions that allow me to answer these questions in most cases: that all of the parameters in my problem are positive, save for one (lets call it *q*), which ranges from -1 to 1.

I have been very impressed with the ability of Mathematica to tear through these questions symbolically — most people would resort to numerical methods in my community. My process is deceptively simple, I make a statement ("There exists values for *Z* parameters for which *X* is negative and *Y* is positive) and then ask *Mathematica* to determine whether that statement is true or false using [`Resolve[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Resolve.html?q=Resolve). It surprisingly works in most cases, and it takes *Mathematica* seconds to perform what used to take me days.

However, sometimes *Mathematica* just plain stalls. Upon asking it to resolve my statement into true or false, it just sits and chews on the question indefinitely. I've left it overnight to no avail.

My question is this: what is *Mathematica* doing behind the scenes to resolve these statements, and how can I help it along?

I've experimented with adding finite bounds to my assumptions, and allowing *Mathematica* to use 'finite precision', but I haven't had much success with the former and I don't fully understand/trust the latter. Feel free to lecture me on what I'm doing wrong as long as its educational.

Comment: Additional detail: If I provide fractional values for some of the parameters in my problem (e.g. a = 1, b = 1, c =1/100), Mathematica resolves them immediately. What's the deal?

Comment: Bill, welcome to the site. Have you looked at `Assumptions` and `Assuming`?

Comment: Most likely it is using CAD, as in cylindrical algebraic decomposition. It may be using other technologies as well, depending on the specifics of the system.

Comment: If not too verbose would be helpful if you can provide an answer where it works and one where it stalls.